# Better way to do computation over pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Below is my pandas snippet. it works. Given a df, I wish to know if there exist any row that satisfy c1> 10 and C2 and C3 are True. Below code works. I wsh to know if there is any better way to do the same.

```
import pandas as pd
inp = [{'c1':10, 'c2':True, 'c3': False}, {'c1':9, 'c2':True, 'c3': True}, {'c1':11, 'c2':True, 'c3': True}]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)

def check(df):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if ((row['c1']>10) & (row['c2']==True)& (row['c3']==True)):
            return True
        else:
            continue

t = check(df)
```

Comment: Broadly speaking, using loops on pandas objects is not efficient. You should explore whether you can use ‘apply’-based approach to arrive at the same result.

Comment: What do you mean by a better way? Better how? What do you want to improve?

Comment: In Python `&` and `and` are different things. You needed `and` because `&` is mainly for integer bitwise operations.

Comment: @Neither while in this case you should use `and` (by selecting an element from a row you get the actual value); note that pandas overloads `&` for its DataFrames and other classes. So in context of pandas it is very common to use `&` and not to use `and` (albeit in the case of the code in question you should use `and`; in my answer below for example you need to use `&` as you combine whole columns)

Comment: @Drecker Yes thanks; hence the "mainly" in the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using pandas you rarely need to iterate over rows and apply the operations per each row separately. In many cases if you apply the same operation to the whole dataframe or column you get the same or similar result and faster a more readable code. In your case:

```
(df['c1'] > 10) & df['c2'] & df['c3']

# will lead to a Series:
# 0    False
# 1    False
# 2     True
# dtype: bool
```

(note that I am calling the operation on the whole `df` rather than single `row`

which signifies for which rows the condition holds. If you need to know just if *any* row satisfies the condition, you can all `any`:

```
((df['c1'] > 10) & df['c2'] & df['c3']).any()
# True
```

So your whole `check` function would be:

```
def check(df):
    return ((df['c1'] > 10) & df['c2'] & df['c3']).any()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want to change or improve about your solution, but you can achieve the same without a separate function and loops as well -

```
df[(df['c1'] > 10) & (df['c2']) & (df['c3'])].index.size > 0
```

Comment: Note that this approach creates redundant dataframe just for a purpose of checking if it is empty. You can achieve the same result whit more straigh-forward way just by calling `any` method

Comment: And no, @Drecker didn't downvote; I did. 1) you didn't explain what's going on 2) your way of doing is not good practice

Comment: Subsetting the frame and checking its unemptiness over its index's size being greater than zero; all instaed of using `any`.

Comment: What is bad about it?

Comment: Unclear in giving the intent

Comment: Adding to the question by @Mortz -- What is Unclear , question asks for a better solution , there can be two aspects of a better code - (1) lesser lines/bytes (2) lesser time taken

Answer (score -1):

The *condition* in question is `(df.c1 > 10) & df.c2 & df.c3`
You can either check if there are `any` rows in the dataframe `df` that satisfies this condition.

```
>>> print(((df.c1 > 10) & df.c2 & df.c3).any())

True
```

or , you can check for the length of the dataframe returned from the original dataframe - for this condition (which will be df[(*condition*)]

```
>>> print(len(df[((df.c1>10) & df.c2 & df.c2)]) > 0)

True
```